# How to modify Page type result of Spring repository search for REST API?

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I have a HotelRepository which has a named method which returns a default `Page<Hotel>` item as result instead of a list.

I want to change the content type `Hotel` to `HotelDto` in the page since the DTO has customized parameter that I'd like to display. I have already a constructor to convert Hotel to HotelDto.

My attempt:

```
Page<Hotel> hotels = dao.findAll(pageRequest);
return new PageImpl<>(
                hotels.getContent().stream()
                        .map(hotel -> new HotelListItemDto(hotel, hotel.getSupplier())).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                pageRequest, hotels.getContent().size());
```

The problem is that it only manipulate one page of the result. Of course, I can get all the results as a list first then create a page based on the list, but it loses the advantage of `Page` (I think returning page would improve the performance of the search request).

So what should I do to keep the page advantage but still have the ability to customize the output?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but can't you just use `Page.map(...)` directly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost did it :)

Unless I'm skipping something, the only thing you need to change is the size that you are passing to the `PageImpl` constructor.

Instead of using `hotels.getContent().size()` (gives you the size of the content on the actual page) you should use `hotels.getTotalElements()` which gives you the total size of the elements in all the pages available.

**Update 1:**

To do it properly, you should change your code for:

```
Page<Hotel> hotels = dao.findAll(pageRequest);
return new PageImpl<>(
                hotels.getContent().stream()
                        .map(hotel -> new HotelListItemDto(hotel, hotel.getSupplier())).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                pageRequest, hotels.getTotalElements());
```

The code from above is going to create a page analog to the `hotels` page. And this is how your parameters are enough for the PageImpl:

1. The first parameter is the list with the content (of type `HotelListItemDemo`) that the new page will have. Since this is just a mapping for the `hotels` content to another type, the number of elements will be exactly the same.
2. The second parameter is the page request, which gives the PageImpl the information about the page size, the page index (and maybe the order, if you requested one).
3. The last parameter is the total number of elements that you would have if you append all the pages available in the query (value returned in the `hotels.getTotalElements()` method). With that, the PageImpl can also calculate things like `hasNext()` that I mentioned in the comments.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But `Page.getContent()` is a list of one single page right? How does new page know if the content is the last/first page (content does not provide page index)?

Comment: Yes, `hotels.getContent()` gives you a list of the values in the actual page. However, `hotels` is an instance of the `Page` type, which has more information about this page and other stuff like the total elements in the pages. If you want to know more about the `Page` properties you can check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html

Comment: By the way, if you want to know if the actual page is the last one, you also have the method `hotels.hasNext()` which returns a boolean.

Comment: I know `hotels` is a correct Page, I'm talking about the new PageImple that I created using a modified `hotels.getContent` list.

Comment: I'm going to edit the answer to give you more details about it. Please give me +1 and accept the answer if you think I was clear. If not, add another comment.

Comment: If I want to filter the page content, and still fill up the empty slot with the content of next pages to keep the number of elements of single page consistent, what should I do?

Comment: I think that the best way to do it is by filter the elements directly in the query. If you don't do that, you will have wrong values for the pageIndex and the total elements. Anyway, if you want to get the next or the previous page, you probably need to make another query with a new `PageRequest`.

Comment: It would probably be easier with `hotels.map(hotel -> new HotelListItemDto(hotel, hotel.getSupplier()))`
Because the parameters aren't going to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `page.getContent()` is unmodifiable, the `map()` function of the page class should be used to maintain the functionality of the page.

```
@Override
public Page<HotelListItemDtodto > findAll(Pageable pageable) {
  Page<Hotel> hotels = dao.findAll(pageable);
  return page.map(this::entityToDTO);
}

private HotelListItemDto entityToDto(Hotel entity) {
    if (entity == null)
        return null;
    
    return new HotelListItemDto(hotel, hotel.getSupplier());
}
```